# User can't have two objectives with the same category - RubyOnRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to implement my create method to avoid the creation of two objectives with the same category.

```
def create
   # submission of new objective form
   @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
   @objective = Objective.new(objective_params)
   @objective.user_id = current_user.id
   @objective.category_id = @category.id
   @objective.start_date = Date.today

   if current_user.objectives.count >= 1 && current_user.objectives.where(category_id: @objective.category_id).exists?
     @used_category = current_user.objectives.where(category_id: @objective.category_id).first.category.id
     if @used_category == @objective.category_id
       flash[:alert] = "Tu as déjà un objectif appartenant à cette catégorie"
     end
   else
     @objective.save!
     if @objective.persisted?
       # creates periods for the objective
       @objective.total_periods.times do |i|
         period =
           {
             period_number:  (Date.today + (i*7).days).strftime("%V"),
             period_score: 0,
             created_at: Date.today,
             objective_id: @objective.id
           }
         p1 = Period.new( period_number: period[:period_number], created_at: period[:created_at], period_score: period[:period_score], objective_id: period[:objective_id])
         p1.save!
       end
     end
   end

   if current_user.objectives.count == 1
     notification = ObjectiveNotification.with(post: Post.where(user_id: User.find_by(username: "Aitio"), title: "Participez à un objectif en commun !")[0])
     notification.deliver(@objective.user)
     notifications = current_user.notifications.unread.count
     Turbo::StreamsChannel.broadcast_replace_to("mynotif", target: "mynotif_#{current_user.id}_value", partial: 'shared/stream_mynotif', locals: { notifications: notifications, userid: current_user.id })
   end



   # replaces form with create.turbo_stream.erb
   respond_to do |format|
     format.turbo_stream
   end
 end
```

But I can't seem to make it work.
I'm wondering if didn't go too far, maybe there is a simpler solution.

If someone has an idea, let me know ! Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I've understood your question correctly, but it seems like a [custom validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) on the model would make more sense in this case as it will prevent the save and flag up the errors on your form in the view without you needing to do those extra checks in your controller.

Something similar to this:

```
class Objective < ApplicationRecord

validates :check_category

def check_category
  if self.user.objectives.where(category_id: self.category_id).present?
    errors.add :category_id, "Tu as déjà un objectif appartenant à cette catégorie"
  end
end
```